# ASP.NET C# ListView ItemCommand não está funcionando

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

Meu `ItemCommand` do `ListView` não funciona. Alguém consegue me apontar se há alguma coisa faltando ou erros no código?

```
 <!-- Primeira Coluna  -->
  <div id="firstCollumn">
  </div>

  <!-- Conteúdo -->
   <div id="contentHome">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"> 
     <ContentTemplate>
            <!-- Resultados da Busca -->
            <div id="Resultados">
                <span>Foram encontrados <%=QuantResultados%> Produtos</span>
            </div>

            <!-- Box para os Produtos (LISTVIEW) -->
            <div id="produto">
                <asp:ListView ID="ListProduto" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID_PRODUTO" 
                onitemcommand="ListProduto_ItemCommand" >
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <h3>
                            Não há produtos a serem mostrados
                        </h3>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <!-- Produto Item -->
                        <div id="produtoBox">

                            <!-- IMAGEM -->
                            <div class="imageProd">
                                <img class="image" src="../../Sessions/Company/img/Produtos/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IMAGEM") %>"  alt="">
                            </div>

                            <!-- DETALHES -->
                            <div id="details">
                                <!-- TITULO -->
                                <div class="description">
                                    <a title="" href="#">
                                        <p class="descricao_desktop">
                                            <span class="span007"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NOME_PRODUTO") %></span>
                                        </p>
                                    </a>
                                </div>

                                <!-- DESCRIÇÃO -->
                                <div class="features">
                                    <span>
                                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DESCRICAO") %>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <!-- PREÇO -->
                                <div id="price" class="Desc01">
                                    <p class="Desc01"><strong> De:</strong><span>R$100</span></p>
                                    <p class="Desc02"><strong> Por:</strong><span><%#String.Format("{0:c}", Eval("PRECO_PRODUTO"))%></span></p>
                                </div>

                                <!-- ADICIONAR A LISTA -->
                                <asp:Button ID="AdicionaLista" class="AddToList" runat="server" CommandName="AdicionarProduto"  Text="Adicionar à Lista.." />


                                 <!-- INFORMAÇÕES DA EMPRESA -->
                                <div id="company">
                                    <img class="logoCompany" src="#"  alt="">
                                    <div class="verEmpresa">Ver empresa</div>
                                    <div class="DescEmpresa">
                                        <strong>
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NOME_FANTASIA") %>
                                        </strong>
                                        <span>
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RAMO") %>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                             </div><!-- FIM DETALHES -->
                       </div><!-- FIM PRODUTO ITEM -->
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                     <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
            </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
    <div id="secondCollumn">
    </div>
```

Comment: Veja esse link https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/4hx47hfe(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Pode colocar na sua pergunta o evento `ListProduto_ItemCommand`?

Comment: Consegui Resolver, era só colocar no botão para não ter AutoPost. Obrigado pela Atenção.

Comment: Seria interessante colocar a resposta e aceitá-la para sua pergunta não ficar em aberto :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Button ID="AdicionaLista" class="AddToList" runat="server" CommandName="AdicionarProduto"  Text="Adicionar à Lista.." Autopostback="false" />
```

**Solução:**

```
Autopostback="false"
```